# Read a config file in python store it into a list then split that into sublists

Tags: python, list, split

I am a beginner in python.
So may be I am repeating the same stuff.

Here the problem goes -->
I have a config file called 
installer_data.txt (which contains)

```
host_ip = 10.5.5.81
services = mesos_master,hdfs_datanode,storm,kafka,zookeeper,pig
host_ip = 10.6.4.31
services = mesos_slave,zookeeper,cassandra,hdfs_namenode
```

I am trying to store the contents via this script -->

```
in_file = open("installer_data.txt","r")
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("installer_data.txt")]
service_types =("mesos_master","mesos_slave","hdfs_namenode","hdfs_datanode","kafka","zookeeper","cassandra","pig")
service = [ f for f in lines if f in service_types]
hosts = [ f for f in lines if f not in service_types]
print service[0]
```

Error

```
Returns Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./file_test.py", line 13, in <module>
    print service[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

As the service list is not populating.
Can you guys point me what I am missing here?

Comment: What output you are wishing?

Comment: @bobd, do you decide on the config file?  If yes you might want to look into https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html or https://pypi.python.org/pypi/configobj/5.0.6

Comment: I am expecting two lists Vishnu ; service_type =['mesos_master','mesos_slave','hdfs_namenode','hdfs_datanode','kafka','zookeeper','cassandra','pig'] and hosts=['10.5.5.81','10.x...',..']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse it using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), it is much easier!

```
import re #import regex
string = open("data.txt","r").read() #load file
regex = re.compile('(.+) = (.+)').findall(string) #look for pattern (.+) = (.+) in 'string'
print regex #print
```

this will output:

```
[('host_ip', '10.5.5.81'), ('services', 'mesos_master,hdfs_datanode,storm,kafka,zookeeper,pig'), ('host_ip', '10.6.4.31'), ('services', 'mesos_slave,zookeeper,cassandra,hdfs_namenode')]
```

You can also convert it to a dictionary, which will make it much better, but becuase you have variables with the same name in the file, it cant be done. Anyway, if you want to change it, you convert it to dict using: `dict(regex)`, which will output: `{'services': 'mesos_slave,zookeeper,cassandra,hdfs_namenode', 'host_ip': '10.6.4.31'}`

Using dictionary is better becuase you can access any variable by **name**, for example: `regex["host_ip"]`. When you use list, you can access only using numbers (`regex[0]`), and if you dont know the order it cant be used.

Comment: Will the regex snippet work with older Python 2.6.6? As I am getting regex = re.compile('(.+) = (.+)')
 formatted_lines= regex.findall(lines)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: @bobd Oops! forgot you are using pytyhon 3.x. I wrote this in Python 2.7. Ill update a 3.x version of the code in a few minutes..

Comment: @ ohad987 -- No, No I am using a rather old Python 2.6.6 :(

Comment: @bobd ohhhh.... my english is not so good lol :) ill check it out now.. BTW, can you update it to 2.7?

Comment: @bobd I tested the code now and it works great! You checked that the file `data.txt` exist?

Comment: My Bad, I am trying to search with findall within a list in side my script. Your code works great! Thanks a ton

Comment: @bobd No problem! if it you think it helped, please accept this answer by clickin the V button! :)